# how to connect the mass products to azure?

Tags: azure, tcp, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I have some question regarding the Azure IoT hub:

- To communicate with Azure hub it is compulsory for the device to have azure SDK?
- the certificate X.509 which we are generating is the same for all the devices?
  eg . If I had produce 100 devices then I will flash the same firmware in all these devices
- can azure IoT hub works on TCP/IP protocol?

Is there any site that has explained how to use azure IoT hub for mass production of devices.

I have also referred following links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/about-iot-dps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-no-sdk
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT Hub accepts any MQTT 3.1.1 client
The certificate represents the device identity, it MUST be unique per device
MQTT works on top of TCP/IP

if you have any comments or feedback about those docs I'd suggest to provide feedback in the docs site.